# Can I install iTunes in windows drive d directly instead of c drive?

Tags: windows-7, installation, itunes, disk-space

I want to install iTunes in D drive as there is limited space in C drive.Is there is any way that i can install the future software downloads in d drive directly other than c drive. I am using windows 7 in which the action needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Most applications provide you with an option of where you want to install software. They may call it "Destination Folder." The default locations, depending on if the application is 32-bit or 64-bit are:

- `C:\Program Files (x86)`  (32-bit programs)
- `C:\Program Files`        (64-bit programs)

*Note: If you have a 32-bit operating system you will only have `C:\Program Files` and it will hold only 32-bit application*s.

It is not uncommon to install applications on a different partition or hard drive. I would recommend creating the above two folders on your D: drive.

Then, when you begin the installation of an application and it asks you where you want to install the software:

- If you see `C:\Program Files\Some Application` change it to `D:\Program Files\Some Application`.
- If you see `C:\Program Files (x86)\Some Application` change it to `D:\Program Files (x86)\Some Application`,

Due to poor programming techniques, there have been some bugs in applications that are installed in alternate program files locations. However, almost all software will work just fine if you do this. The operating system doesn't care where they are.

It appears iTunes used to not allow you to install on a drive other than C:. However, it appears recent versions of the software give you the option to change the destination folder.

[image]

If you expect a large iTunes Media Folder then you may also be interested in moving the media folder to your D: drive also. This will save your music and other items on the D: drive.

[Locate and organize your iTunes media files](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204668)

If you want to change the default location that all programs install in then you can modify the following two values in the registry:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir (x86)`

However, please note that Microsoft does NOT support doing this and recommends against it: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/933700/microsoft-does-not-support-changing-the-location-of-the-program-files